# Ubuntu failed to detect monitor and very low resolution?

Tags: resolution, monitor

I tried different versions of Ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10 beta, but got same problem.

My desktop pc configuration is, 
 - intel core i5 2400
 - DH67BL Motherboard
 - Inbuilt motherboard graphics - No extra graphics card attached
 - Acer-H193HQV 18.5" Monitor
 - 2GB RAM
 - 250GB Harddisk

Problem : Ubuntu can't detect my monitor and saying it Unknown. Moreover, monitor's original resolution is 1366x768 but in the list of resolution there is only 1024x768 and 800x600 are there.

Comment: Did Bruno Pereira's answer work?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try to install a new graphics driver for your system, a ppa with the newest drivers can [be found here](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver).

Add it with

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
```

and after that do

```
sudo apt-get update` and a `sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` using the command `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`.